# Is $f(a)=0^{\prime}$ bijective homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:(R,+,.)\rightarrow (R^{\prime},+^{\prime},.^{\prime})$, and

$f(a)=0^{\prime}$, $\forall a \in R$.

Is $f$ bijective homomorphism?

My answer is no because $f$ is not injective function so its not a bijective function therefore $f$ is not bijective homomorphism.

Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps to answer we need to know what the symbols stand for.

Comment: If both $R$ and $R'$ are the zero ring, then $f$ is a bijective homomorphism.  Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bijective map, unless both $R$ and $R'$ are the trivial ring.

If $R$ contains more then one element it is not injective, if $R'$ contains more than one element it is not surjective. 
Yet if both contain exactly one element the map is bijective, and
in this case it is also a homomorphism.

If your rings are supposed to have a multiplicative identity element, the map is not a homomorphism, unless $R'$ is the trvial ring. (As the multiplicative idenity needs to be mapped to the multiplicative identity.)

In short, it is a bijective homomorphism if and only if both rings are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order for a homomorphism to be a bijection, it has to be both injective and surjective and you are correct that this function is definitely not injective. In fact, it is also not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

So f maps any x in one field into the additive identity of another?  Looks like a no-brainer.  Yes you are correct.  But I would check to see if that is really what the problem says!